# Finding $a,b$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3}-ax-b)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3}-ax-b)=0.
$$
What is the value of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Does not matter what $a$ and $b$ are, the first term increases faster, so the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: Apparently he meant cube root, not square root.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\left(1+x^2+x^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} &=  x\left(1+\frac{1+x^2}{x^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
&=  x\left(1+ \frac{1+x^2}{3x^3} +o(\frac{1}{x})\right) \\
&=  x+ \frac{1}{3} + o(1) \\
&\Rightarrow  a=1,b=\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: why put & before = is better?

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left( x + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{9x}  \right)^3 \; \;  < \; \; x^3 + x^2 + 1 \; \; <  \; \; \left( x + \frac{1}{3}   \right)^3 $$
for, say, $x \geq 3 \; , \; \;$ as
$$  x^3 + x^2 - \frac{5}{27}  + \frac{1}{81 x^2} - \frac{1}{729x^3}   \; \;  < \; \; x^3 + x^2 + 1 \; \; <  \; \;  x^3 + x^2 + \frac{x}{3} + \frac{1}{27} $$
so with  $x \geq 3 \; , \; \;$ we have
$$   x + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{9x}   \; \;  < \; \; \sqrt[3]{ \; \; x^3 + x^2 + 1 \; \; \; \; } \; \; <  \; \;  x + \frac{1}{3}    $$
$$    - \frac{1}{9x}   \; \;  < \; \; \; \; \sqrt[3]{ \; \; x^3 + x^2 + 1 \; \; \; \; } \; \; - \; \; x \; - \; \frac{1}{3} \; \; \; \; \; <  \; \;  0    $$

Answer (score 0):

**Original Question:**

In fact,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1+x^{2}+x^{3}}-ax-b&>x^{3/2}-ax-b\\
&=x^{3/2}\left(1-\dfrac{a}{x^{1/2}}-\dfrac{b}{x^{3/2}}\right),
\end{align*}
and that $1-a/x^{1/2}-b/x^{3/2}$ is actually strictly positive for large $x>0$, so the whole term tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3}-ax-b&=\frac{(1+x^2+x^3)-(ax+b)^3}{(\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3})^2+(ax+b)\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3}+(ax+b)^2}\\
&=\frac{(1-a^3)x^3+(1-3a^2b)x^2-3ab^2x+(1-b^3)}{(\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3})^2+(ax+b)\sqrt[3]{1+x^2+x^3}+(ax+b)^2}\\
&=\frac{(1-a^3)x+(1-3a^2b)-\frac{3ab^2}{x}+\frac{1-b^3}{x^2}}{(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x}+1})^2+(a+\frac{b}{x})\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x}+1}+(a+\frac{b}{x})^2}
\end{align*}

As $x\to\infty$, the limit exists if and only if $1-a^3=0$, i.e., $a=1$.

When $a=1$, the limit is $\displaystyle\frac{1-3b}{3}$.

So, $\displaystyle b=\frac{1}{3}$.